# Surjectivity of composition of functions

Tags: measure-theory, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Assume $F: X\rightarrow Y$ and $G: Y \rightarrow Z$ are surjective prove that $G \circ F$ is surjective.

Let $z\in Z$ Set x$\in X$ to be such that $F(x)=y$ and $G(y)=z$ (these exist because F and G are both surjective). Hence $(G \circ F)(x)$ $=G(F(x)) =G(y)=z$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: OK.perhaps like that. $z \in Z$. Since g surj. there is a $y \in Y$ such that $g(y)=z$. Since f is surj.there is a $x \in.X$ s.t. $f(x)=y,$ hence $g(f(x))=z$ , i.e. $g\circ f$ is surj.